# run a cmd command in c#

Tags: c#, cmd

I want to run a CMD command from my c# programm, but I do not find the mistake i make.
Here are the gloabl variables:

```
string flasherpath = "C:\ti\MSP430Flasher_1.3.1\MSP430Flasher.exe";
string chip = "-n MSP430G2553";
string hexpath = " -w \"C:\ti\MSP430Flasher_1.3.1\LED_Controle.txt\"";
```

this is the Code:

```
private bool programm()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         if (check[i] == false)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Please choose working Settings.");
             return false;
         }
     }
     MessageBox.Show("All Right start Programming in the CMD Window.");
     string command = "/C ";
     command += "\"" + flasherpath + "\" "+chip+" "+hexpath+" -v -g -z [VCC] & pause";
     Process.Start("cmd", command);        
     return true;
}
```

But everytime I run the code only this appears:

> "Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die
>   Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch. Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste .
>   . ."

Google Translate:

> The syntax for the file name, directory name, or volume label syntax
>   is incorrect. Press any button

I do not understand this error, because if I copy command (without the "/C") in a normal cmd window and run it the result I expect comes back.

Do some see my mistake?

Comment: What does `/C` mean? Did you define it as an argument in your main method?

Comment: `hexpath` has some escaped characters that don't look like they should be escaped. You might want to add in some back-slashes there on that path.

Comment: /C Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates.

Comment: -w "C:\ti\MSP430Flasher_1.3.1\LED_Controle.txt" thats it how hexpath look like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape your strings:

Mask your backslashes `"\"` either as `"\\"` with a leading backslash or set an `@` before the string:
`string somestring = @"here is some gibberish with a \ in it";`, just like you do with `"`. You can use the @ for flasherpath. But because you need to escape the `"` as well in hexpath, here you will have to work with manual \

```
string flasherpath = @"C:\ti\MSP430Flasher_1.3.1\MSP430Flasher.exe";
string chip = "-n MSP430G2553";
string hexpath = " -w \"C:\\ti\\MSP430Flasher_1.3.1\\LED_Controle.txt\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
string command = "/C \"";
command += "\"" + flasherpath + "\" "+chip+" "+hexpath+" -v -g -z [VCC] & pause \"";
```